# Updating the value displayed in a GUI with Python: Revised (new difficulties)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having some trouble developing a GUI to my needs. I'm using Tkinter and Python and I have reviewed all that I can find on the topic with no success.

So here's my situation:

#### Background

I'm working on developing a controlled environment that maintains a user set temperature and pressure. I have a pretty expansive program that is written and functional for the control and logging of the pressure component. Basically it uses threading to simultaneously take user inputs, control an actuator, log the data, and all that for just the pressure. The original intent was to spot check the temperature and go from there. In the development it became clear that simultaneously logging and displaying the temperature would be supremely more useful than not doing so. The temperature is measured with a thermocouple and parlayed through a DAQ to acquire this data. I am an engineer so programming is not my nature, but I have completed a few online python tutorials and believe to have a "working" knowledge (used loosely) of the language.

#### Program

So I set out to develop a new piece of my existing program. The functions I've used and developed seem to work for what I want. I am able to access the desired port on the DAQ, read and store the value, convert the voltage using an imported function (aka I know it works). I have it currently configured to print each value, so that I can check these, and have been satisfied with the results in command line. I developed this functionality as a separate program which will be integrated into the already existing program, but did it as such due to some funky hardware limitations, but so for now, what I'm working on is simply it's own program.

#### Now, the problem:

So I have working functions but need to integrate them into my GUI. The GUI, if it were functional, would simply display a button, "get temp", and label "Temperature: XX" where the XX would display the temperature as retrieved and converted by the program. My problems are related to the updating of the XX value. I'm able to run the necessary function and store the result to a variable but can't seem to figure out how to get it displaying and updating. I've read up on .get() and .set(value) in Tkinter but haven't been able to get it to work through several iterations. The closest I have gotten is to get 0.0 or PY_VARXX where the Temperature should be. GUI shown below

GUI

[image: GUI]
I suspect my problem may be related to the structure of my program. The code that produced the GUI is here:

```
import LabJackPython
import u3
import sys
import getopt
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Toplevel, Label, Entry, StringVar, DoubleVar
import tkMessageBox
from datetime import datetime, date

#define global variables
v1 = None
g_get = None
Gain = None
GainE = None
VoltE = None
g_Conv = None
vv1 = None
vr1 = None
v2 = None
vread = None
CJT = None
T1 = None
T1C = None

#configure DAQ
d = u3.U3()
d.configIO(FIOAnalog = 12)

#define functions
#voltage to temperature conversion
def VTT(v, voff, gain):
    global v1, T1, vread, CJT, Gain
    vread = d.getAIN(2)
    v = vread
    CJT = d.getTemperature()
    gain
    if v > 14.9:
        print "Invalid Input"
    else:
        v1 = (v - voff)/gain
        T1 = LabJackPython.TCVoltsToTemp(LabJackPython.LJ_ttJ, v1, CJT)
        print "vread:", vread
        print "v:", v
        print "v1:", v1
        print "CJT:", CJT
        print "T1 (K):", T1

#run VTT on button click with fixed values
def assign(event):
    global T1C
    VTT(1, 1.25, 201)
    T1C = T1 - 273.15
    print "T (C):", T1C

#initiate GUI   
def main():
    global v1, T1, vread, CJT, Gain
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Temp")

    Temp = Frame(root)
    Temp.grid()

    TempL = Label(Temp, text = "Temperature:", font = 20)
    TempL.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    #Define variables
    T1C = DoubleVar()
    T1C1 = DoubleVar()
    T1C1.set(T1C)
    #variable
    Temperature = Label(Temp, textvariable = T1C1, font = 20)
    Temperature.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    #button
    g_get = Button(Temp, text = "get temp", height = 2, width = 10)
    g_get.bind("<Button-1>", assign)
    g_get.grid(row = 2, column = 0)


    try:
        root.mainloop ()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Keyboard Interrupt Caught!"

    exit()
```

Any help anyone can give is great. If there's anything I did that could be done better I'm open to hearing about it as well. I don't know much in the way of code conventions or best practices. I'm sure there's plenty wrong with the code but first and foremost I'm concerned with circumventing the problem and getting the value of T1C to display in the GUI.

Thanks, everyone

EDIT: My response to the class approach as opposed to using global variables is that, when integrating back into the larger program, I will need to be able to access the value of T1C (or T1, or T1C1, it's all essentially the same) in multiple places. One function is generating the value and another will need to retrieve the value and write it to a logfile and the value will need to be displayed and updated in the GUI. The final integration will not be a button based approach but rather the button is there for my use in development. In re-integration, the VTT will run continuously and write to the logfile every .2 seconds or so, concurrently with the pressure and time of the reading. I can provide the code for this larger, first program but it is quite ridiculous and I don't know how much sense it will make outside of the context in which it is used. Let me now if this would help my explanation make more sense.

EDIT2: So based on the recommendation to construct the GUI using a class based approach I tried to rebuild it from the ground up and have what I think is a much more logical program still with difficulties, but thank you for the help guys.

Comment: Please don't edit a question and ask an additional question. As it is, your question is extremely difficult to follow. SO isn't designed for extended discussions. Each question should ask one thing.

Answer (score 2):

### A fast solution:

Code as-is "destroys" the quasi-global `DoubleVar()` held in `T1C` variable inside `assign()` by re-assignment of another value.

```
assign(event):
    global T1C
    VTT(1, 1.25, 201)
    T1C = T1 - 273.15            # shall rather read  T1C.set( T1 - 273.15 )
    print "T (C):", T1C          # shall rather read  print "T [C]:", T1C.get()
```

### A clean & extensible solution for GUI add-on:

Refactor the code into a Class-based approach, so that it

1. Encapsulates both the `<controller>`-part device-read-ing(s) and
   `<model>`-part with all `<state>`-variable(s) ( Class-wide re-used & protected )
2. Allows for a smart & smooth GUI integration, as the Class is ready to serve it's `<visual>`-part layer
3. Avoids `global` variables ( can & shall rely on Class-instance variable "inside" it's own encapsulation container ... no other error/mistake/bad-will would ever destroy your control values )

Comment: Your fast solution is a step in the right direction, but I believe T1C will still be `None` at this point, because the `T1C` assignment in `main` is acting on a local variable, not the global one. He also needs to make `T1C` the `textvariable` of `Temperature`, not `T1C1`... But yeah, 100% agree on the "clean" suggestions.

Comment: @Kevin Right, remarks both on the chained `T1C` **->** `T1C1` ( which does not thus get served well in the `.mainloop()`-MVC ). Refactoring is IMHO the proper step into a stable, maintainable & reliable design, extensible into a self-contained or other-hierarchy controlled GUI-framework.